# jquery alter links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I'm looking for a bit of code (jquery if possible) that will remove any file extensions from links. For example

```
directory/page.html to directory/page
directory2/page2.cfm to directory2/page2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: if you want to have clean url, probably for SEO reasons, it's better to use `.htaccess` to rewrite the url. This is used by apache. Check this tool http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery can only select the elements for you, but not process the strings. Simple string manipulation will do it:

```
$('a').attr('href', function(i, value) {
    return value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf('.'));
});
```

`lastIndexOf` is only supported in IE9 though, so maybe you have to use a regular expression:

```
return value.replace(/\..+$/, '');
```

**Update:** Regarding your comment, that's even simpler, just use

```
 return value.replace(/\.cfm$/, '');
```

You could also restrict the set of links, by only selecting those that actually end with `.cfm`:

```
$('a[href$=".cfm"]')
```

Comment: Just removing everything after the last '.' will potentially break a lot of links that he doesn't want modified. Something like `http://www.test.com/` would become `http://www.test`

Comment: @Anthony: True... there are various solutions to this problem. The easiest would be if all these links share a common class. If the OP provided more information, the answer would be better ;)

Comment: hi guys, In an ideal world I would like to remove any '.cfm' file extensions from all the link on the page. Is that possible?

Comment: That's amazing. Solved all my problems. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure whether this would work, but you could try using the .remove and set the element to file extension,

http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Really not sure to be honest.

There is also a simpler way of doing this without any jQuery however, what you could do is name all files index.extension and place them in according folders from the root, for example

new.html would be renamed to index.html then placed in a directory named news, then when someone would type www.yourdomain.com/news/ it would directly open the necessary page, maybe a bit simpler than jQuery.

Comment: `remove` removes elements from the DOM. It doesn't do anything even close to removing part of a string.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('a[href]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').substring(0, value.lastIndexOf('.')));
});
```